# Traversing variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I am interested in printing out a variadic number of templated arguments. 
So far I have implemented the code below but run into the following compile-time errors

```
./include/AView.hpp:46:5: error: call to member function 'indexcalc2' is ambiguous
    indexcalc2<Strs...>();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/AView.hpp:46:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'myView<double, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4,
      5>::indexcalc2<4, 5>' requested here
./include/AView.hpp:46:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'myView<double, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4,
      5>::indexcalc2<3, 4, 5>' requested here
./include/AView.hpp:52:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'myView<double, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4,
      5>::indexcalc2<2, 3, 4, 5>' requested here
    indexcalc2<Strides...>();
    ^
main.cpp:23:9: note: in instantiation of member function 'myView<double, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>::indexcalc' requested here
      A.indexcalc();
        ^
./include/AView.hpp:36:8: note: candidate function [with Str0 = 5]
  void indexcalc2() const
       ^
./include/AView.hpp:43:8: note: candidate function [with Str0 = 5, Strs = <>]
  void indexcalc2() const
```

The idea here is to create a layout struct with a get method that will output the first template argument stride. I then created a second struct called view with an indexcalc method which would generate a layout, print the stride, and recursively peal template arguments by calling indexcalc2.

Unfortunately, I don't quite have the correct implementation and wondering if there might be suggestions.

```
template<size_t... Strides>
struct layout
{
  static size_t get(size_t idx0) {return idx0;};
};

template<size_t stride0, size_t... Strides>
struct layout<stride0, Strides...> : layout<Strides...>
{

  static size_t get()
  {
    std::cout<<"Stride is : "<<stride0<<std::endl;
    return stride0;
  }
};


template<typename T, size_t DIM,size_t Stride0,  size_t... Strides>
struct myView
{
  myView() {};

  template<size_t Str0>
  void indexcalc2() const
  {
    std::cout<<layout<Str0>::get()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"End"<<std::endl;
  }

  template<size_t Str0, size_t... Strs>
  void indexcalc2() const
  {
    std::cout<<layout<Str0,Strs...>::get()<<std::endl;
    indexcalc2<Strs...>();
  }

  void indexcalc() const
  {
    std::cout<<layout<Stride0, Strides...>::get()<<std::endl;
    indexcalc2<Strides...>();
  }

};


int main()
{
struct myView<double,2,1,2,3,4,5> A;
A.indexcalc();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems here:

```
  template<size_t Str0> void indexcalc2() const;
  template<size_t Str0, size_t... Strs> void indexcalc2() const;
```

will result in the same instance if `Strs` contains no elements. So you have an ambiguous instance here which is already complained by the compiler:

```
./include/AView.hpp:46:5: error: call to member function 'indexcalc2' is ambiguous
indexcalc2<Strs...>();
```

So the idea by unwinding a parameter set is always to have an empty specialization like:

```
  template<> void indexcalc2() const;
```

so that a call from

```
 indexcalc2<Strs...>();
```

goes to that specialization  if `Strs` is empty.

But after this you will run into the next trouble:

Specialization of templates can not be done in the class scope. So you must specialize outside like:

```
template<> void myView::indexcalc2<>() const;
```

But your `myView` is also a template and it is not allowed to specialize your method without fully specialize the class parameters!

If you go with c++17 you simply can use `constexpr if`to get rid of all that problems, but in c++11 you have to go over specializing with an encapsulating class.

Your templated class with templated methods is to complex to simply write down a complete solution here for you.

Comment: Thanks, would you have suggestions for an alternative approach?

Comment: @user2785954: If you find the answer helpful, you should upvote instead of commenting. And if the answer is correct, you should accept it, so that others see that the answer help them also!